# Gridview onclick

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, onclick

This "alternate" & "normal" give different color to the background of the rows

```
    If (e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Alternate) Then
        e.Row.CssClass = "alternate"
    Else
        e.Row.CssClass = "normal"
    End If
```

if i click on a row background change color:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.style.background='LightCyan';")
```

work's fine.

So every time I click on a row the background changes.
I would like that when the user clicks on a different row the background changes and undo the background of the other.
Any ideas?

Comment: welcome. You're going to want to be more specific with your question and tags. I can't tell whether you're talking about Android, WinForms, Qt or baby seals. I'm not even sure what language you're working in--VB?

Comment: This is a webform on VS2010 NET4. As twip point it out. this has to be done as soon the onclick is trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the original color of the highlighted row so that it returns when a different row is highlighted, try the following solution.

JavaScript on the page:

```
    var lastStyle;
    var lastRowID;

    function highlightRow(rowID, updatedStyle) {
        var rowClicked = document.getElementById(rowID);
        restoreRowColor(lastRowID, lastStyle);

        lastStyle = rowClicked.className;
        lastRowID = rowID;

        rowClicked.className = "highlightRow";      
    }

    function restoreRowColor(rowID, originalStyle) {
        var previousRowClicked = document.getElementById(rowID);

        if (previousRowClicked != null) {              
            previousRowClicked.className = originalStyle;
        }
    }
```

---

Styles on the page

```
.normalRow{background-color: #FFFFFF;}
.alternateRow{background-color: #D3D3D3;}
.highlightRow{background-color: #F0E68C;}
```

---

Code

```
Private Sub myGridView_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, 
    ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) 
    Handles myGridView.RowCreated

    Dim rowID As String = "row" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString

    If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Normal Then
        e.Row.CssClass = "normalRow"
    ElseIf e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Alternate Then
        e.Row.CssClass = "alternateRow"
    End If

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("id", rowID)
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
            "highlightRow('" & rowID & "', '" & e.Row.CssClass & "')")
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Works in Chrome 12, Firefox 3.6, and IE 8 (as those are what I have on hand).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the trouble is that you want the table to maintain its previously styled alternating row colors after the click events are processed?

A couple of possible solutions:

1. Restyle the whole grid each time you click and then process the highlight, which isn't terribly efficient.
2. Store the row ID of the previously highlighted row and its color before it was highlighted. Then when you process the click, restore the color of the previous row and highlight the row just clicked.

Comment: point #1 as you said not efficient but lets say that the gridview is 10 rows max everytime. How do i go to re-style?

Comment: point #2 That's exactly what i want to accomplish but if im adding the onclick to the row's. can i just ..."onlick","change background" then... where do i write the code to do the rest?

Comment: Do you need to handle this server-side? What's the purpose of highlighting the row? If you don't have to post back each time, you might consider handling this with JavaScript.

Comment: The purpose of highlighting is that after many clicks the user wants to know which is the last one. ("i know, i know"). So how can this be done on JavaScript or jQuery or CSS or any other. How and where can i add the code that at the same time the highlighting gets apply and the other one undone.

Comment: A few more questions: Are you binding to data? How does the table get populated? Is the table static, or will you be modifying the data you display in some way?  What event contains your alternating row color code? I think I can help here, but dynamic + gridview is the shortbus to frustration.

Comment: I think I've found a solution. Since there's some discussion here, I'm going to post a new answer for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

Your wording is a bit confusing, but I think I understand what you're asking.

When you are running this line of code:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.style.background='LightCyan';")
```

You can add your gridview color right before that line to reset it each time you are running that method

```
GV_Id.RowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```